# YUM Config file for a repo in local drive

Tags: yum, package-management, repository

I have a repo in my local computer .
I was told to create a config file like

```
[Norf-repo]
name="Norf repo"
baseurl=http://location
enabled=1
```

But since it is a local package  , I cant probably look at having some local address instaed of http:// ?
In the latter case I need APACHE which needs to be configured /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your baseurl is wrong

```
baseurl=file:///path/to/repo/
```